# Using Occlusion Culling with Asset Bundles in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle, occlusion-culling

I am working on a web based Unity project with large number of objects and textures. So I am using Asset Bundles to load assets dynamically in scene. 
Is there any way to use Occlusion culling on a scene that contains Objects loaded and Instantiated from Asset Bundle?